# Rails create hash for each new model created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, md5

Whenever new models are created in Rails the `id` field is used to identify it.

I was wondering if there is a neat way to create a unique hash whenever a model is created in a similar fashion to the id.

Comment: You can add a column, and assign this attribute on a before_create callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a persistent unique hash, you could add a column called `unique_id` and do something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :generate_unique_id

  def generate_unique_id
    # generate a random hex string using trickery:
    self.unique_id = rand(36**12).to_s(16) # => "22b0433e3d9ae776"
    # generate a 12-char random string a-z0-9:
    self.unique_id = rand(36**12).to_s(36) # => "os0w9cl8xi48"
    # or, if you want to do something more obvious:
    self.unique_id = SecureRandom.hex(6) # => "ba191acc80ef"
    # or, if you want a legitimate UUID:
    self.unique_id = SecureRandom.uuid # => "72569edd-1841-4fd9-af05-edf66a58b74b"
  end
end
```